# Exhausted memory error

Tags: php

I am getting reports from users of blank screens when going to register for an event. This does not happen for most users.
The PHP error log says:

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 400572416 bytes) in /home/sclgulf/public_html/sclgulf/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 520`

There is no error in the CiviCRM log in the ConfigAndLog directory.
I have tried allocating 1GB instead of 512MB and it makes no difference.
Can anyone help me debug this please?

Comment: Can you comment out the `var_dump` statement at line 520? Then it should show the actual error when it happens. I think it's running out of memory trying to dump the variable before it gets to say what the error is.

Comment: Hi, "There is no error in the CiviCRM log in the ConfigAndLog directory." that seems odd - can you double-check the permissions on the directory? Also would you mind updating your question with which version of CiviCRM you're on, and which payment processors you are using [on that event]? Also whether you're using PHP FPM or Apache's mod php?

Answer (score 2):

As per @Demerit's comment, and somewhat counter-intuitively, make sure you've got your debugging settings to "off" - it's running out of memory when reporting the error. If you turn the various debugging settings off, it'll still report quite a lot of detail of the error.

Comment: Many thanks Alan for your comments, and @Demerit too.

Comment: I am seeing a long [warning] as follows when a payment is created (and is not marked complete by the dummy payment processor):

Comment: Jan 10 09:49:17  [warning] Deprecated function CRM_Core_OptionGroup::getValue, use CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getKey.
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)

Jan 10 09:49:17  [warning] Deprecated code: We have merged input params into the property bag for now but please rewrite code to not use this.

Jan 10 09:49:17  [warning] Deprecated code: Unknown property 'qfKey'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty ...

Comment: Sorry, I cannot post the whole set of warnings as there is not enough characters in this message. But there are dozens of similar lines of warning about deprecated code. I am running latest Civivcrm 5.21 on Drupal 8

Comment: Ah, cool. That new PropertyBag code just got merged recently, you might have encountered an issue with it. https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/82
What payment processor are you using?

Comment: Running into issues that have thrown errors  (ConfigAndLog) re: civi-tag deprecated and "Property bag" using Webform registrations with Stripe (D7 and Civi 5.21).   (No memory issue just failure to complete transactions under certain conditions)

Comment: @DaveT - you'll want to create a new post with more details if you want anyone to look at that.

Comment: Thanks, will do